FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED, Dynamic Routing on sveltekit and vercel
I have a svelte project where I use dynamic routes that works the local but not after deploying to vercel. In particular what does not work is just the page with the dynamic route, this is the error:

This Serverless Function has crashed.
Your connection is working correctly.
Vercel is working correctly.
500: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
Code: FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED

The serverless function that vercel is referring to is this:
<script context="module" lang="ts">
  import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
  import type { ServerLoad } from '@sveltejs/kit';

  export const load: ServerLoad = async ({ params }) => {
    const db = getFirestore();

    // Verifica prima che params.id sia definito
    if (!params.id) {
      return { status: 400, error: new Error('ID documento non valido') };
    }

    const id = decodeURIComponent(params.id);
    const docRef = doc(db, "pdf", id);

    try {
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        const data = docSnap.data();
        if (typeof data.url === 'string') {
          return {
            props: {
              pdfUrl: data.url,
              pdfId: id
            }
          };
        }
      } else {
        return { status: 404, error: new Error('Documento non trovato') };
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return { status: 500, error: new Error('Errore nel recupero del documento') };
    }
  }
</script>
  
<script lang="ts">
  import PdfViewer from "$lib/components/organisms/PdfViewer.svelte";
  export let pdfUrl: string;  // Assicurati che sia sempre stringa, gestisci undefined nella logica del componente se necessario
  export let pdfId: string;   // Assicurati che sia sempre stringa, gestisci undefined nella logica del componente se necessario
</script>
  
<main>
  <PdfViewer pdfUrl={pdfUrl} pdfId={pdfId} />
</main>

I hope someone can help me!
Unfortunately, I wasn't able to do much since I'm not a particularly savvy programmer and I'm not familiar with vercel

What version of SvelteKit is that? load functions have not been defined in module scripts for a very long time now, this has to be a < v1 version. Please upgrade to a stable release first.
